# How position a text inside div inside image?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to know where I made a mistake or where should I add something?

1. How to replace hours on third blue div on bottom to the right site? I was trying and shearching, but I can't see solution. Please let me know what to change and maybe also can You recomend me tutorial or articles with that case.
2. When I hover over a menu button, I'd like the text to turn white, but when i change it like color: #fff i doesn't work.

[Sc1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T1k9S.jpg)
[Sc2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Bj1j.jpg)

```css
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.header{
    background-image:url(Images/bg.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100vh;
    position: relative;
}
.menubar{
    background: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    position: static;
}
.menubar ul{
 display: inline-flex;
    list-style: none;
    color: black;
}
.menubar ul li{
    width: auto;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 15px;
}
.menubar ul li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}
.active, .menubar ul li:hover{
    background-color: #2E8BC0;
    border-radius: 2px;
    color: white;
}
.menubar .fas, .menubar .far{
    margin-right: 8px;
}
.sub-menu-1{
    display: none;
}
.menubar ul li:hover .sub-menu-1{
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    background: #040c7a;
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-left: -15px;
}
.menubar ul li:hover .sub-menu-1 ul{
    display: block;
    margin: 10px;
}
.menubar ul li:hover .sub-menu-1 ul li{
    width: 100px;
    padding: 10px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
    background: transparent;
    border-radius: 0;
    text-align: left;
}
.menubar ul li:hover .sub-menu-1 ul li:last-child{
    border-bottom: none;
}
.menubar ul li:hover .sub-menu-1 ul li a:hover{
    color: #278eff;
}
.fa-angle-right{
    float: right;
    margin-left: 8px;
}
.class-menu-2{
    display: none;
}
.hover-me:hover .class-menu-2{
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    margin-top: -40px;
    margin-left: 110px;
    background: #040c7a; 
}
.row1{
    color: white;
    display:flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: transparent;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    
}
.text-box1{
    background-color: #2E8BC0;
    height: 150px;
    width: 300px;
    display: block;
}
.text-box1 h3{
    padding: 10px;
    font-size:15px;
    text-align: left;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
.text-box1 p{
font-size: 25px;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: left;
    margin-left: 20px;
    display: flex;
}
.text-box1 p2{


}
.hero-btn{
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    padding: 12px 34px;
    font-size: 13px;
    background: transparent;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-left: -40px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
.hero-btn:hover{
    border: 1px solid white;
    background: white;
    transition: 1s;
    color: black;
}
.text-box1 p a{
    color: white;
}
.text-box1 ul li{
    font-size: 17px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    display:flex;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted white;
}
.text-box1 ul li:last-child{
    border-bottom: none;
}
.text-box1#first{
    background-color: #0C2D48;
}
.text-box1#second{
    background-color: #145DA0;
}
.text-box1#third
    background-color: #2E8BC0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    
    <title>Przychodnia</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="PrzychodniaStyle.css">
    
    
</head>
<body>
<section class="header">
        <div class="menubar">
<ul>
<li class="active"><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-home"></i>Strona głowna</a></li>
<li><a href="#"><i class="far fa-address-card"></i>Specjalistyka</a>
    <div class="sub-menu-1">
        <ul>
            <li class="hover-me"> <a href="#">Menu</a><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i>
                <div class="class-menu-2">
                    <ul>
                        <li> <a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                        <li> <a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                        <li> <a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                </li>
            <li class="hover-me"> <a href="#">Menu</a><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i>
            <div class="class-menu-2">
                    <ul>
                        <li> <a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                        <li> <a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                        <li> <a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li> <a href="#">Menu</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</li>
<li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-motorcycle"></i>Stomatologia</a>
    <div class="sub-menu-1">
        <ul>
            <li> <a href="#">Menu</a></li>
            <li> <a href="#">Menu</a></li>
            <li> <a href="#">Menu</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div></li>    
<li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-toolbox"></i>Poradnie POZ</a></li>    
<li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-graduation-cap"></i>Medycyna Pracy</a></li>    
<li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-flag-checkered"></i>Diagnostyki</a></li>    
<li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-user-plus"></i>Laboratorium</a></li>  
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-user-plus"></i>O nas</a></li> 
<li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-mobile-alt"></i>Kontakt</a></li>  
</ul>
</div>
    <div class="row1">
    <div  class="text-box1" id="first">
    <h3>Rejstracja telefoniczna</h3>
    <p>+1234567890</p>
    </div>
        <div  class="text-box1" id="second">
    <h3>Rejstracja elektroniczna</h3>
    <p class="e"><a href="#">przychodnia@eu.pl</a></p>
    <a href="" class="hero-btn">Formularz kontaktowy</a>
    </div>
        <div  class="text-box1" id="third">
    <h3>Godziny otwarcia</h3>
    <ul>
        <li><p1>Poniedziałek</p1><p2>6:00-18:00</p2></li>
            <li>Wtorek</li>
        <li>Środa</li>
        <li>Czwartek</li>
        <li>Piątek</li>
            
            </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
        
    </section>  
    <section>
    
    
    
    <div class="text-box1">
        Lolz
        
        </div>
        <a href="" class="hero-btn">Formularz kontaktowy</a>
    </section>
    
    
    
</body>



</html>
```

Comment: Replacing the hours means editing the HTML where it says `<p2>6:00-18:00</p2>`. As for the white text, your `.menubar ul li a` is more specific and overriding the other one. You need `.menubar ul li:hover a` https://jsfiddle.net/reukvw5z/

Comment: For the secon one it is working fine thanks! But for the replecing hours I have problem with editing, because with for exampel position: absolute and right: 1px; it's going out of div. I would like to have something like that:
[Screen](https://i.ibb.co/RgZy3fF/sc3.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add `justify-content: space-between` ([documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content)) :

```css
.text-box1 ul li{
    font-size: 17px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    display: flex;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted white;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```

2. As recommened by [@Chris G](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5734311/chris-g), use a more specific selector :

```
.menubar ul li:hover a {
    color: white;
}
.active, .menubar ul li:hover {
    background-color: #2E8BC0;
    border-radius: 2px;
}
```

```css
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.header{
    background-image:url(Images/bg.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100vh;
    position: relative;
}
.menubar{
    background: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    position: static;
}
.menubar ul{
 display: inline-flex;
    list-style: none;
    color: black;
}
.menubar ul li{
    width: auto;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 15px;
}
.menubar ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}
.menubar ul li:hover a {
    color: white;
}
.active, .menubar ul li:hover {
    background-color: #2E8BC0;
    border-radius: 2px;
}
.menubar .fas, .menubar .far{
    margin-right: 8px;
}
.sub-menu-1{
    display: none;
}
.menubar ul li:hover .sub-menu-1{
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    background: #040c7a;
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-left: -15px;
}
.menubar ul li:hover .sub-menu-1 ul{
    display: block;
    margin: 10px;
}
.menubar ul li:hover .sub-menu-1 ul li{
    width: 100px;
    padding: 10px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
    background: transparent;
    border-radius: 0;
    text-align: left;
}
.menubar ul li:hover .sub-menu-1 ul li:last-child{
    border-bottom: none;
}
.menubar ul li:hover .sub-menu-1 ul li a:hover{
    color: #278eff;
}
.fa-angle-right{
    float: right;
    margin-left: 8px;
}
.class-menu-2{
    display: none;
}
.hover-me:hover .class-menu-2{
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    margin-top: -40px;
    margin-left: 110px;
    background: #040c7a; 
}
.row1{
    color: white;
    display:flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: transparent;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    
}
.text-box1{
    background-color: #2E8BC0;
    height: 150px;
    width: 300px;
    display: block;
}
.text-box1 h3{
    padding: 10px;
    font-size:15px;
    text-align: left;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
.text-box1 p{
font-size: 25px;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: left;
    margin-left: 20px;
    display: flex;
}
.text-box1 p2{


}
.hero-btn{
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    padding: 12px 34px;
    font-size: 13px;
    background: transparent;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-left: -40px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
.hero-btn:hover{
    border: 1px solid white;
    background: white;
    transition: 1s;
    color: black;
}
.text-box1 p a{
    color: white;
}
.text-box1 ul li{
    font-size: 17px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    display:flex;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted white;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
.text-box1 ul li:last-child{
    border-bottom: none;
}
.text-box1#first{
    background-color: #0C2D48;
}
.text-box1#second{
    background-color: #145DA0;
}
.text-box1#third{
    background-color: #2E8BC0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    
    <title>Przychodnia</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="PrzychodniaStyle.css">
    
    
</head>
<body>
<section class="header">
        <div class="menubar">
<ul>
<li class="active"><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-home"></i>Strona głowna</a></li>
<li><a href="#"><i class="far fa-address-card"></i>Specjalistyka</a>
    <div class="sub-menu-1">
        <ul>
            <li class="hover-me"> <a href="#">Menu</a><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i>
                <div class="class-menu-2">
                    <ul>
                        <li> <a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                        <li> <a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                        <li> <a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                </li>
            <li class="hover-me"> <a href="#">Menu</a><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i>
            <div class="class-menu-2">
                    <ul>
                        <li> <a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                        <li> <a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                        <li> <a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li> <a href="#">Menu</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</li>
<li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-motorcycle"></i>Stomatologia</a>
    <div class="sub-menu-1">
        <ul>
            <li> <a href="#">Menu</a></li>
            <li> <a href="#">Menu</a></li>
            <li> <a href="#">Menu</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div></li>    
<li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-toolbox"></i>Poradnie POZ</a></li>    
<li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-graduation-cap"></i>Medycyna Pracy</a></li>    
<li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-flag-checkered"></i>Diagnostyki</a></li>    
<li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-user-plus"></i>Laboratorium</a></li>  
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-user-plus"></i>O nas</a></li> 
<li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-mobile-alt"></i>Kontakt</a></li>  
</ul>
</div>
    <div class="row1">
    <div  class="text-box1" id="first">
    <h3>Rejstracja telefoniczna</h3>
    <p>+1234567890</p>
    </div>
        <div  class="text-box1" id="second">
    <h3>Rejstracja elektroniczna</h3>
    <p class="e"><a href="#">przychodnia@eu.pl</a></p>
    <a href="" class="hero-btn">Formularz kontaktowy</a>
    </div>
        <div  class="text-box1" id="third">
    <h3>Godziny otwarcia</h3>
    <ul>
        <li><p1>Poniedziałek</p1><p2 class="hour">6:00-18:00</p2></li>
            <li>Wtorek</li>
        <li>Środa</li>
        <li>Czwartek</li>
        <li>Piątek</li>
            
            </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
        
    </section>  
    <section>
    
    
    
    <div class="text-box1">
        Lolz
        
        </div>
        <a href="" class="hero-btn">Formularz kontaktowy</a>
    </section>
    
    
    
</body>



</html>
```